# Как сделать так, чтобы текст в TEdit имел парольные символы?

Tags: delphi, radstudio

Не могли бы вы мне сказать как сделать так, чтобы при записи текста в компонент TEdit, символы были парольными?(Если что, я делаю программу на Delphi 10.4) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В инспекторе объектов или в [хелпе](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit_Properties) можно обнаружить свойство `PasswordChar`

Comment: Извините, а какое значение мне надо выставить там?

Comment: Например, звёздочку '*'.

Comment: Большое спасибо!